# TornadoFx TabPane - Side = left and label rotate style

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

- .tab-container {
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
        -fx-rotate: 90;    }

how do convert to tornadofx? My Tab header label need to be aligned when side.Left.Please help on this

Answer (score 1):

TornadoFX doesn't make any changes to the TabPane container, so exactly the same CSS and properties would work for a TornadoFX application. I think you meant .tab-pane instead of .tab-container though. If you want to write the same using type safe CSS, it would be:

```
tabPane {
    backgroundColor += Color.TRANSPARENT
    rotate = 90.deg
}
```